# How can I write long mathematically results in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I want to write out some math calculations in javascript like this:

```
let bruteforce = "ThisIsATest";
console.log(bruteforce.length ** 26);
```

My problem is that the result isn't a full number rather this: 1.191817653772721e+27.
Its with a 'e+' at the end. How can I write out a full result with only numbers like in python?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 0):

For big numbers, you could use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to do the calculation to preserve the precision:

```js
let bruteforce = "ThisIsATest";
console.log((BigInt(bruteforce.length) ** 26n).toString());
```